# How to use word embeddings (i.e., Word2vec, GloVe or BERT) to calculate the most word similarity in a set of N words?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity

I am trying to calculate the semantic similarity by inputting the word list and output a word, which is the most word similarity in the list.

E.g.

If I pass in a list of words

```py
words = ['portugal', 'spain', 'belgium', 'country', 'netherlands', 'italy']
```

It should output me something like this-

```py
['country']
```

Comment: I think this may not be the case of embedding. It is the case how you define `the most word similarity`. I am wondering what you really want to output.

Answer (score 8):

**GloVe Embeddings**

To load pre-trained GloVe embeddings, we'll use a package called `torchtext`. It contains other useful tools for working with text that we will see later in the course. The documentation for torchtext GloVe vectors are available at: https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vocab.html#glove

Begin by loading a set of GloVe embeddings. The first time you run the code below, Python will download a large file (862MB) containing the pre-trained embeddings.

```
import torch
import torchtext

glove = torchtext.vocab.GloVe(name="6B", # trained on Wikipedia 2014 corpus of 6 billion words
                              dim=50)   # embedding size = 100
```

Let's look at what the embedding of the word "car" looks like:

```
glove['cat']
```

> tensor([ 0.4528, -0.5011, -0.5371, -0.0157,  0.2219,  0.5460, -0.6730,
> -0.6891,
> 0.6349, -0.1973,  0.3368,  0.7735,  0.9009,  0.3849,  0.3837,  0.2657,
> -0.0806,  0.6109, -1.2894, -0.2231, -0.6158,  0.2170,  0.3561,  0.4450,
> 0.6089, -1.1633, -1.1579,  0.3612,  0.1047, -0.7832,  1.4352,  0.1863,
> -0.2611,  0.8328, -0.2312,  0.3248,  0.1449, -0.4455,  0.3350, -0.9595,
> -0.0975,  0.4814, -0.4335,  0.6945,  0.9104, -0.2817,  0.4164, -1.2609,
> 0.7128,  0.2378])

It is a torch tensor with dimension (50,). It is difficult to determine what each number in this embedding means, if anything. However, we know that there is structure in this embedding space. That is, distances in this embedding space is meaningful.

**Measuring Distance**

To explore the structure of the embedding space, it is necessary to introduce a notion of distance. You are probably already familiar with the notion of the Euclidean distance. The Euclidean distance of two vectors x=[x1,x2,...xn]
and y=[y1,y2,...yn] is just the 2-norm of their difference x−y.

The PyTorch function `torch.norm` computes the 2-norm of a vector for us, so we can compute the Euclidean distance between two vectors like this:

```
x = glove['cat']
y = glove['dog']
torch.norm(y - x)
```

> tensor(1.8846)

**Cosine Similarity** is an alternative measure of distance. The cosine similarity measures the angle between two vectors, and has the property that it only considers the direction of the vectors, not their the magnitudes. (We'll use this property next class.)

```
x = torch.tensor([1., 1., 1.]).unsqueeze(0)
y = torch.tensor([2., 2., 2.]).unsqueeze(0)
torch.cosine_similarity(x, y) # should be one
```

> tensor([1.])

The cosine similarity is a similarity measure rather than a distance measure: The larger the similarity, the "closer" the word embeddings are to each other.

```
x = glove['cat']
y = glove['dog']
torch.cosine_similarity(x.unsqueeze(0), y.unsqueeze(0))
```

> tensor([0.9218])

**Word Similarity**

Now that we have a notion of distance in our embedding space, we can talk about words that are "close" to each other in the embedding space. For now, let's use Euclidean distances to look at how close various words are to the word "cat".

```
word = 'cat'
other = ['dog', 'bike', 'kitten', 'puppy', 'kite', 'computer', 'neuron']
for w in other:
    dist = torch.norm(glove[word] - glove[w]) # euclidean distance
    print(w, float(dist))
```

> dog 1.8846031427383423

> bike 5.048375129699707

> kitten 3.5068609714508057

> puppy 3.0644655227661133

> kite 4.210376262664795

> computer 6.030652046203613

> neuron 6.228669166564941

In fact, we can look through our entire vocabulary for words that are closest to a point in the embedding space -- for example, we can look for words that are closest to another word like "cat".

```
def print_closest_words(vec, n=5):
    dists = torch.norm(glove.vectors - vec, dim=1)     # compute distances to all words
    lst = sorted(enumerate(dists.numpy()), key=lambda x: x[1]) # sort by distance
    for idx, difference in lst[1:n+1]:                         # take the top n
        print(glove.itos[idx], difference)

print_closest_words(glove["cat"], n=10)
```

> dog 1.8846031

> rabbit 2.4572797

> monkey 2.8102052

> cats 2.8972247

> rat 2.9455352

> beast 2.9878407

> monster 3.0022194

> pet 3.0396757

> snake 3.0617998

> puppy 3.0644655

```
print_closest_words(glove['nurse'])
```

> doctor 3.1274529

> dentist 3.1306612

> nurses 3.26872

> pediatrician 3.3212206

> counselor 3.3987114

```
print_closest_words(glove['computer'])
```

> computers 2.4362664

> software 2.926823

> technology 3.190351

> electronic 3.5067408

> computing 3.5999784

We could also look at which words are closest to the midpoints of two words:

```
print_closest_words((glove['happy'] + glove['sad']) / 2)
```

> happy 1.9199749

> feels 2.3604643

> sorry 2.4984782

> hardly 2.52593

> imagine 2.5652788

```
print_closest_words((glove['lake'] + glove['building']) / 2)
```

> surrounding 3.0698414

> nearby 3.1112068

> bridge 3.1585503

> along 3.1610188

> shore 3.1618817

**Analogies**

One surprising aspect of GloVe vectors is that the directions in the embedding space can be meaningful. The structure of the GloVe vectors certain analogy-like relationship like this tend to hold:

*king−man+woman≈queen*

```
print_closest_words(glove['king'] - glove['man'] + glove['woman'])
```

> queen 2.8391209

> prince 3.6610038

> elizabeth 3.7152522

> daughter 3.8317878

> widow 3.8493774

We get reasonable answers like "queen", "throne" and the name of our current queen.

We can likewise flip the analogy around:

```
print_closest_words(glove['queen'] - glove['woman'] + glove['man'])
```

> king 2.8391209

> prince 3.2508988

> crown 3.4485192

> knight 3.5587437

> coronation 3.6198905

Or, try a different but related analogies along the gender axis:

```
print_closest_words(glove['king'] - glove['prince'] + glove['princess'])
```

> queen 3.1845968

> king 3.9103293

> bride 4.285721

> lady 4.299571

> sister 4.421178

```
print_closest_words(glove['uncle'] - glove['man'] + glove['woman'])
```

> grandmother 2.323353

> aunt 2.3527892

> granddaughter 2.3615322

> daughter 2.4039288

> uncle 2.6026237

```
print_closest_words(glove['grandmother'] - glove['mother'] + glove['father'])
```

> uncle 2.0784423

> father 2.0912483

> grandson 2.2965577

> nephew 2.353551

> elder 2.4274695

```
print_closest_words(glove['old'] - glove['young'] + glove['father'])
```

> father 4.0326614

> son 4.4065413

> grandfather 4.51851

> grandson 4.722089

> daughter 4.786716

We can move an embedding towards the direction of "goodness" or "badness":

```
print_closest_words(glove['programmer'] - glove['bad'] + glove['good'])
```

> versatile 4.381561

> creative 4.5690007

> entrepreneur 4.6343737

> enables 4.7177725

> intelligent 4.7349973

```
print_closest_words(glove['programmer'] - glove['good'] + glove['bad'])
```

> hacker 3.8383653

> glitch 4.003873

> originator 4.041952

> hack 4.047719

> serial 4.2250676

**Bias in Word Vectors**

Machine learning models have an air of "fairness" about them, since models make decisions without human intervention. However, models can and do learn whatever bias is present in the training data!

GloVe vectors seems innocuous enough: they are just representations of words in some embedding space. Even so, we'll show that the structure of the GloVe vectors encodes the everyday biases present in the texts that they are trained on.

We'll start with an example analogy:

*doctor−man+woman≈??*

Let's use GloVe vectors to find the answer to the above analogy:

```
print_closest_words(glove['doctor'] - glove['man'] + glove['woman'])
```

> nurse 3.1355345

> pregnant 3.7805371

> child 3.78347

> woman 3.8643107

> mother 3.922231

The *doctor−man+woman≈nurse* analogy is very concerning. Just to verify, the same result does not appear if we flip the gender terms:

```
print_closest_words(glove['doctor'] - glove['woman'] + glove['man'])
```

> man 3.9335632

> colleague 3.975502

> himself 3.9847782

> brother 3.9997008

> another 4.029071

We see similar types of gender bias with other professions.

```
print_closest_words(glove['programmer'] - glove['man'] + glove['woman'])
```

> prodigy 3.6688528

> psychotherapist 3.8069527

> therapist 3.8087194

> introduces 3.9064546

> swedish-born 4.1178856

Beyond the first result, none of the other words are even related to programming! In contrast, if we flip the gender terms, we get very different results:

```
print_closest_words(glove['programmer'] - glove['woman'] + glove['man'])
```

> setup 4.002241

> innovator 4.0661883

> programmers 4.1729574

> hacker 4.2256656

> genius 4.3644104

Here are the results for "engineer":

```
print_closest_words(glove['engineer'] - glove['man'] + glove['woman'])
```

> technician 3.6926973

> mechanic 3.9212747

> pioneer 4.1543956

> pioneering 4.1880875

> educator 4.2264576

```
print_closest_words(glove['engineer'] - glove['woman'] + glove['man'])
```

> builder 4.3523865

> mechanic 4.402976

> engineers 4.477985

> worked 4.5281315

> replacing 4.600204

Answer (score 3):

First, **pretrained word2vec trained on Google News** needs to be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit.

Then, **the cosine similarity** between the embedding of words can be computed as follows:

```
import gensim
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm

def cosine_sim(a,b):
    return dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))

# load the w2v model
path_pretraind_model='./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'  #set as the path of pretraind model 
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(path_pretraind_model, binary=True)


wlist = ['portugal', 'spain', 'belgium', 'country', 'netherlands', 'italy']
lenwlist=len(wlist)
avrsim=[]
#compute cosine similarity between each word in wlist with the other words in wlist  
for i in range(lenwlist):
    word=wlist[i]
    totalsim=0
    wordembed=model[word] 
    for j in range(lenwlist):
        if i!=j:
            word2embed=model[wlist[j]] 
            totalsim+=cosine_sim(wordembed, word2embed)
    avrsim.append(totalsim/ (lenwlist-1)) #add the average similarity between word and any other words in wlist   

index_min=avrsim.index(min(avrsim)) #get min similarity        
print(wlist[index_min])
```

By similarity if you mean **the cosine similarity between the embedding of words**, "country" has the least similarity to other words.

Comment: Note also there's an existing utility method, `.doesnt_match()`, for calculating which word is *least similar* to the average-of-all-the-words: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.doesnt_match – & someone who wanted a 'most central' calculation could model it after that method's source code.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but when I applied to this list
wlist=[ 'screen',  'memory', 'laptop', 'processor']
It appeared that the screen is the most similar.

Comment: Note that the code above finds the least similar word to others. Because you wanted to get country, and country has the least similarity to the other words in ['portugal', 'spain', 'belgium', 'country', 'netherlands', 'italy']. If you want to get the most similar one,  you need to use index_min=avrsim.index(max(avrsim)) instead of min(avrsim).  In case of wlist=[ 'screen', 'memory', 'laptop', 'processor'], the least similar word to others is screen and the most similar is laptop.